# SEO - Is it right that only 20% of visitors come on the homepage?

Tags: seo, statistics

few days ago I was discussing with a xoogler about percentage of people incoming on a website, and how many of them really come on the homepage.

He said that in a website that has been studied well only the 20% of traffic comes from the homepage. I didn't know much about this percentage so I ran to my computer to find out more, but I couldn't find nothing about this percentage. Of course make a xoogler speak is pretty hard, so I'd prefer to make a search by myself, do you have any link of knowledge about this?

I understand that the homepage does not have the "really" content an user may be searching for, but I'd read more about who and where did take this percentages.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Note that, as per the FAQ, this is a site for "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face". Speculative questions which don't really have a definite answer ("20% of visitors come through front page?" that very much depends on the type of site that you run, and would vary wildly) are not a good fit for this site. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Just check some of my websites that I manage and the data seems to check out, but I never thought about it like that.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, why not? For my website it's 8.89%. That's because the content people are looking for on my website are the articles. That's where they're directly going either from search engines queries or links on other websites the vast majority of the time. They have no interest in my home page or even who I am. It makes sense to me.

Comment: My experience and thoughts exactly. An e-commerce site I'm working on shows less than 5% of traffic landing on the homepage.. More importantly, none of the converting traffic lands on the home page FIRST, so not really an issue. :)

Comment: @Anonymous - It's also why an effective site search sells more product. They don't want your home page and they don't want your site navigation. Just gimme! <grin> It's why most SEO dudes who call telling you they ran your website through WooRank often miss the boat. They often sell SEO optimization for home pages, not individual product pages that need to rank high for their specific subject, just like blog articles...

Answer (score 0):

Heh, why SEO is so hard. You're SEO'ing your whole website, not just a home page.

The people who come in on your home page are likely the people who already know you and put in your domain name or have bookmarked it to get to your site.

People searching on Google, et. al. want to get to the meat, it's why they're searching.

The page they land on has to be what they're really interested in, whether it's a product, a service or just information.

Break your website into logical pages, title each one well, provide headings to break that page up into logical units **and say something about that page's particular content in more than a one liner**. If you don't know how to write good copy, hire someone in **your** (not SEO) industry who does and knows your line of content.